# combine 3 rows (with two columns) into columns (6) - per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like that:

```
        Name  colA   colB
row1    John   a      b
row2    John   c      d
row3    John   e      f
row4    Anna   g      h
row5    Anna   i      j
row6    Anna   k      l
```

and I would like to have something like that:

```
        Name  colA1  colB1  colA2  colB2  colA3  colB3
row1    John   a       b      c      d      e      f
row2    Anna   g       h      i      j      k      l
```

It will be always 3 rows per user.

Comment: Can you please post your sql, whatever you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then a end) as a_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then b end) as b_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then a end) as a_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then b end) as b_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then a end) as a_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then b end) as b_3
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by name order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```